# Specifying covariant generic contraint when class references `this` contravariantly

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write some classes that heavily reference each other. The problem is that TypeScript does not like the constraint on `Filter`'s `TContext` generic. When attempting to create a `Filter`, it claims that `DiffContext` does not satisfy the constraint `Context`.

My guess is that `TContext` is actually invariant because it has a property that references `this` contravariantly. Is there a way to specify the generic constraint successfully?

```
class Context {
    pipe?: Pipe<this>;
}

class DiffContext extends Context {
    delta: unknown;
}

type Filter<TContext extends Context> = (context: TContext) => void;

class Pipe<TContext extends Context> {
    filters: Filter<TContext>[];

    constructor(filters: Filter<TContext>[]) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    process(context: TContext) {
        for (const filter of this.filters) {
            filter(context);
        }
    }
}

// Error: Type 'DiffContext' does not satisfy the constraint 'Context'.
const testFilter: Filter<DiffContext> = (context) => {
    console.log(context.delta);
};

const pipe = new Pipe<DiffContext>([testFilter]);
const context = new DiffContext();
pipe.process(context);
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7ALgUwB7OgbwFDQOgAcBLI1AfgC5oAFM1AHmQAsSIA+AblwF9dcoSDAAiJAGbiEKDFlmpEAExjS0mHPkKLUIZGBoBXRAGtE8AO6Ie-XMgCe5aADESu1ACdGAFVWzo8pRUkNWQOaABeaAAKYGDZGh84zABKCLCAN3gSRR5BcCg6Bm9fdQDlOCTQjUJocVc0dwgaFzdPRJlMDgBtAF1cmtjECGR3A2BkeHcoutam53qPYsruntS8GprWdgA6GYaYSL2PCB4amxqid3hgVCgYyoSS5DXNDdrJ6MHh2oX3aHhxNAthBdr8IC83m8jlNBiFkqdIfwznwBAB6VHQACi7iu7gSDlQ0AA5GJJE8idBFPBbtAzFgIGBkOxxHYgSxCV8RmASChieTtoIkN80MMWg1mr9GKSpMsIp9KqlwmF1oQvvAQKhtiB4ABze4dZDbbS6MDwvi5TnEBhyxCocyFchSiQyg0cKJdEXIMUeVY8S2wvyRW326VPKJm0jkbaXa63CD6uE8IA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
class Context<T extends Context<T>> {
    pipe?: Pipe<T>;
}

class DiffContext extends Context<DiffContext> {
    delta: unknown;
}

type Filter<TContext extends Context<TContext>> = (context: TContext) => void;

class Pipe<TContext extends Context<TContext>> {
    filters: Filter<TContext>[];

    constructor(filters: Filter<TContext>[]) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    process(context: TContext) {
        for (const filter of this.filters) {
            filter(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Playground link is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7ALgUwB7IDwBVobUQBMYEUDcA%20S6AbwChonoAHASxdQH4AuaABQ6oqAbnoBfevVCQYAETYAzRWTSZ8mVMVJI12BctUEaDZtCKoQyMHwCuiANaJ4Ad0RjJ9ZAE9O0AGJsVqgATrhG6gRaJHC6FDgRyNTQALzQABTAcZh8CdnIAJSpNABu8GxEYtLgUAJC4fkahDGJDeSYyabMikFoIRB8gcFhee1JANoAulVmWYgQyCG2wMjwIek9wwMBvaFtepRTRV1mTMgAFmwQAHSbfTBpd6EQYmaeZiwh8MCoUJn5uUSx0YpyYijWGTmC2gTxC0HgimgFyut12-WBoNBsP%20YwKr0xkjeEikAHoSdAAKIhL4hXK%20VDQADkBhU%20UZ5ngv2gzmQ0AgYGQV0U3iR5wZUMWYDYKCZiUZ12kSGhaAWQz6gzRWBZiRoaRxeiKKRMIKYUPgIFQ1xA8AA5vqCNcLFYwHiJFUJawhKluagXHVOFqlKyxpR0uMVcg1aFJq6PXM9N7EL7oNr8ulY-lHZZrN6ACxidica6fb6-CD2zCuoA). This is a more explicit declaration of type constraints than `Pipe<this>` because you know `this` must extend `Context` so you have an implicit circularity. Warning I am no typescript expert.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I didn't have to add another generic and was hoping that somehow the reference to `this` would make it work without one, but your solution makes sense.

Comment: I'd encourage you to check out the typescript project to see exactly why your original doesn't compile. You may solve a bug or discover a condition that is actually dangerous if your original was allowed to compile... but it could just be an implementation detail that is not worth it to solve differently.